# malloc vs posix_memalign

Tags: alignment, malloc, posix

I am developing a cache efficient transpose algorithm using tiling and I noticed that when I allocate the  memory with `malloc` I get worse performance than when using `posix_memalign`. More specifically :

Using malloc :  98.7 mSec
Using posix  :  86.4 mSec (for data alignments of 32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096)

I am allocating an array of 32-bit integers.

I can't explain why posix-x, where 4096>x>32 and x is the data alignment, provides always more or less the same efficiency for this range of data alignment values. In my algorithm I am pre-fetching cache lines (64 bytes) so I would expect that for x=64 I would have the best performance numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I did a simple test,when aligned with 8 bytes,the performance is best.
`malloc` use 8 bytes align by default. I tried `posix_memalign` to make 
align larger, but that doesn't make performance better.And performace
has only a little difference with aligned by 8 bytes.